# Announce socket disconnection to previously joined rooms

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I'm new to socket.io 1.1. From what I understand, upon connection loss/disconnection, the server-side socket automatically leaves all rooms and `disconnect` is fired. By the time `disconnect` is fired, `socket.rooms` is already cleared.

I would like to announce to the previously joined rooms that the current user had left. Are those previously connected room ids stored somewhere? Alternatively, is there some sort of `onLeaveRoom` or `beforeDisconnect` mechanism built into socket.io where the room ids can be intercepted?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the list of rooms the client is currently in on disconnect event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830415/get-the-list-of-rooms-the-client-is-currently-in-on-disconnect-event)

Comment: Probably store them in variables in your Node.JS code?..

Comment: @DerM, That is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks for spotting the duplicate. And thanks for answering that other question as well!