# double sockets in room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I press F5 repeatedly without stopping the same socket.username enters the room, generating a list of duplicate names. By spending time, this sockets duplicated vain automatically disconnecting .

I tried with these lines after disconnecting and not work!

`delete io.sockets.adapter.sids[socket.id];
delete io.sockets.adapter.rooms[socket.id];`

How can I avoid this? Tks.

// SERVER.JS

```
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
  if (handshakeData.headers.cookie) {
    handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
    handshakeData.sessionID = cookieParser.signedCookie(handshakeData.cookie['sec_session_id'], 'secret');
    if (handshakeData.cookie['sec_session_id'] != handshakeData.sessionID) return accept('Cookie is invalid.', false);
  } else return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false); 
  accept(null, true);
});




io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    socket.on('adduser', function(name, room, picuser, codeuser, operation) {

        var handshakeData = socket.request;  
        var cookies = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);       
        if(name.length > 0)
        {
            if (!io.sockets.adapter.sids[socket.id][room]) {

                var newCookie = changeCookie(cookies.sec_session_id);
                cookiesSockets[cookies.sec_session_id] = newCookie;
                cookiesSockets2[newCookie] = socket.id;             
                socket.color = getRandomColor();
                socket.username = name;
                socket.room = room;
                socket.newid = newCookie;
                socket.picuser = picuser;
                socket.codeuser = codeuser;             
                // add the client's username to the global list
                usernames[name] = name;
                // send client to room
                socket.join(room);              
                // echo to client they've connected
                socket.emit('updatechat', socket.picuser, socket.codeuser, socket.color, getClock(), 'You', 'join in '+room+'.', room, 0, 0, getClock2(), operation);
                // echo to room 1 that a person has connected to their room
                socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('updatechat', socket.picuser, socket.codeuser, socket.color, getClock(), name,'join in room.', room, 0, 0, getClock2(), 3);

                //update id's private chats on socket disconnecting and connecting...
                if (SocketsUsernames[name])
                {
                    if (SocketsUsernames[name]!=cookies.sec_session_id)
                    {
                        var cookieReal = SocketsUsernames[name];
                        var cookieChanged = cookiesSockets[cookieReal];
                        delete cookiesSockets[cookieReal];
                        delete cookiesSockets2[cookieChanged];
                        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit('updatechatpvt', room, cookieChanged, newCookie);
                    }
                }
                SocketsUsernames[name] = cookies.sec_session_id;
                updateUsers(room);
            }
            else 
            socket.emit('updatechat',null, null, null, null, null, null, room, null, null, null, 7);            
        }       
    });



socket.on('disconnect', function(){     
            if (socket.username)
            {
                // remove the username from global usernames list
                delete usernames[socket.username];          
                socket.leave('myroom');     
            }
        }); 

});
```

//CLIENT.JS

```
socket.on('connect', function (){
            // Retrieve the object from storage CHATROOM!!

            var retrievedRooms = localStorage.getItem('myRooms');
            console.log('retrievedRooms: ', JSON.parse(retrievedRooms));
            if (retrievedRooms && Object.keys(JSON.parse(retrievedRooms)).length>0)
            Object.keys(JSON.parse(retrievedRooms)).forEach(function(key) {
                if (key)
                {
                    myRooms[key]=key;               
                    socket.emit('checkuser', key, function(callback){
                        if(!callback) socket.emit('adduser', $('#modalPerfil').attr('data-username'), key, $('#modalPerfil').attr('data-picuser'), $('#modalPerfil').attr('data-userid'), 1);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

// SOLUTION IN CLIENT.JS - ***setTimeout***

```
socket.on('connect', function (){
            // Retrieve the object from storage CHATROOM!!          
            var retrievedRooms = localStorage.getItem('myRooms');
            console.log('retrievedRooms: ', JSON.parse(retrievedRooms));
            if (retrievedRooms && Object.keys(JSON.parse(retrievedRooms)).length>0)
            Object.keys(JSON.parse(retrievedRooms)).forEach(function(key) {
                if (key)
                {
                    myRooms[key]=key;

                    setTimeout(function(){

                        socket.emit('checkuser', key, function(callback){
                            if(!callback) socket.emit('adduser', $('#modalPerfil').attr('data-username'), key, $('#modalPerfil').attr('data-picuser'), $('#modalPerfil').attr('data-userid'), 1);
                        });

                    }, 1000);                   

                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code.  F5 will reload that page.  That will disconnect the previous socket and connect a new one.  It will all work fine if your code is correct.  You don't have to manually remove things from the adapter.  socket.io does that for you when the previous socket disconnects which it will do when the page is reloaded.

Comment: @jfriend00 ask question updated! tks for attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is causing you a couple problems:

```
socket.onclose = function (reason) {
    roomsToLeaveClient = socket.rooms;
    Object.getPrototypeOf(this).onclose.call(this, reason);
});
```

First off, There's an extra `)` at the end that is closing off your `.on('connect')` block.

That then causes your `socket.on('disconnect', ...)` code to be outside the scope of `socket` so it probably isn't getting called appropriately.  I'd suggest you don't need to listen for a close event at all.  You can just listen for the disconnect event and do any of your cleanup business there.

And, since you're off one set of parens in that code, there's probably a corresponding error somewhere else in your code that still allows things to parse properly.  Putting your code in a linter like http://jshint.com shows these types of errors.

Then, if you really did want to override `.onclose`, you can't just call the prototype version.  Instead, you have to save the version that was in place before you assign your override and call that one.  That's the only way the is compatible with any other overrides.  But, you really ought to just be using `.on()` with event names to watch socket lifecycle things, then you don't have to worry about proper overrides in any way.

I can't tell right away if there are other issues, but this is a glaring one that needs to be fixed first.

Also, you do not need your `roomsToLeaveClient` handling.  socket.io will automatically remove a disconnecting client from any rooms that it is in.  That is not something you need to do.

If you want to know what rooms a socket is in so you can tell the other members of that room that you are leaving, then socket.io has a data structure that tells you exactly what rooms the socket is in and you can just iterate that data structure.  You don't have to keep track of that yourself.

Comment: `There's an extra) at the end que is closing off your .on ('connect') block.`

When copying and pasting manually edited the `stackOverflow` i put a ')` unintentionally! I sobrescrevi the `onclose` to get the full list of rooms to disconnect.`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25830415/get-the-list-of-rooms-the-client-is-currently-in-on-disconnect-event/25864163`.

Comment: @FábioZangirolami - So, what does that comment mean?  I don't 'understand.  The code in your question is wrong.  If that's not your real code, then edit the code in your question to be the real code and leave a comment if you change it.  Not much we can do here, but comment on the code you post.

Comment: sorry. I will do this!

Comment: I removed the `socket.onclose = function (reason) { ... }` of my code and yet the problem persisted, and I do not know what to do =/

Comment: Unfortunately I did not found the problem. But I resolved with `setTimeout` with a time of 1 second to enter the room.